# Book on indefinite inner product

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, inner-products, book-recommendation

I am studying a book on "Hyperbolic Geometry". It start with the The Lorentzian inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\dots -x_ny_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I find it interesting and want to learn about the Geometry of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with an indefinite inner product.I know a book on indefinite inner product by J Bognar.

Please suggest me some books to learn the Geometry of the indefinite inner product space.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at Barrett O'Neil's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry*.

Comment: A particular case is the Minkowski space-time dot product $x_1x'1+x_2x'_2 - tt'$

Comment: Maybe a book about special relativity. Not general.